# Does the following code violate strict aliasing?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

Does the following code violate strict aliasing?

```
int a = 0;
*((int *)((char *)&a)) = 1;
```

**Why not?** because we end up dereferencing the pointer of int `a` using `int *` which is legit

**Why yes?** because we cast the `char *` to `int *` and dereferencing it (the `int *`), which seems as a strict aliasing violation

Comment: AFAIR any object can be accessed with a `char *` without violating the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Why do you think the `char *` is dereferenced at some point in this code?

Comment: yes, but the other way (using `int *` to alias `char *`) is the problematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is valid.  It is allowed to convert between two object pointer types  and back provided there are not alignment issues, and converting to a `char *` is explicitly allowed to access an objects representation (i.e. read the individual bytes).

Section 6.3.2.3p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type.  If the resulting  pointer  is  not  correctly 
>   aligned for  the  referenced  type,  the  behavior  is undefined. 
>   Otherwise, when  converted  back  again,  the  result  shall  compare 
>   equal  to  the original pointer.  When a pointer to an object is
>   converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the
>   lowest addressed byte of the object.  Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining
>   bytes of the object.

Since you covert from `int *` to `char *` then back to `int *`, there are no strict aliasing violations here.

Comment: `If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type` how can I know whether two objects are correctly aligned? (not with respect to the specific question in this post, but in generally) is it that the modulo of their sizes is zero?

Comment: @user2162550 Alignment is implementation defined, but in general basic types start at an address that is a multiple of their size.  An array will have the same alignment as the base type, and a struct will have alignment equal to the largest member’s base type.

Answer (score 2):

The strict aliasing rules do not care about intermediate casts.  They only care about the type of the pointer ultimately used to access an object, and the original type of the object itself (technically its "effective type", but that's not important right now).

In your example code, you take the address of an `int`.  The result has type `int *`. You cast that pointer to `char *`, you cast it again to `int *`, and only then do you dereference it.  The type of the pointer used in the access is `int *` and the type of the object pointed to is `int`, so the strict aliasing rules have no problem.

You are correct that the strict aliasing rules are asymmetric with respect to `char`, but that only matters when either the type of the object itself is `char` or the type of the pointer used in the access is `char`:

```
char x[sizeof(int)] = { 0 };
*(int *)x = 1;  // undefined behavior

int y = 1234;
*(char *)y = 0; // valid; value of y becomes unspecified
```

Theoretically, a cast between two pointer types can lose information, but not when casting from some other type to `char *` and back again.  Also, this is only relevant on computers that you are very unlikely to encounter nowadays.  I can't actually remember an example.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a violation.

> *because we cast the `char *` to `int *`*

You are missing the part the the `char *` you mentioned was actually an `int *`. Thus, finally the access to an `int` type is made via a pointer to `int` - this is perfectly valid.